# how to store postman respone content-type:- text/plain to a variable?

Tags: postman

on hitting the API request using GET method, i get the response content-type as text/plain; and it is a token (example:- ejusgjksdflksdfkjdfksdhfkds). how to store this response token to a variable using script in postman.

Any test script for this?

Thanks.

Comment: With what programming language do you want to do this? And do you mean with "storing to a variable", storing to a file?

Comment: tried using this const respo = pm.response.json(responseBody);
console.log(respo); But in console got error as JSON Error | unexpected token

Comment: So JavaScript, just use the FetchAPI for this simple task. Here's a code example: `const response = await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json');
const myJson = await response.json();
console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));`

Comment: using javascript.

Comment: @GeorgeWalt ; Console o/p Syntaxerror | unexpected error . And after adding the above code to tests in postman, line 1 and 2 shows error as "missing ; before statement"

Comment: What does the actual response body look like? This is the wrong syntax `pm.response.json(responseBody)` the correct syntax is `pm.response.json()` but that's only useful if the body is JSON. You would need `pm.response.text()` and then store the variable using `pm.environment.set("token", <token value>)`

Comment: Thanks got it. var respo1=pm.response.text();
console.log(respo1);
pm.environment.set("token",respo1);

Answer (score 1):

derived from @danny's answer in the comments,

use `pm.response.text()` when the response header type is text/plain.

ex:

```
pm.globals.set("my-token", pm.response.text());
console.log(pm.globals.get("my-token")); // the variable value will outputs to postman console
```